# DSpace's OAI servlet uses wrong baseUrl

Tags: dspace

I use the following Tomcat context descriptor named `OAIHandler.xml` to deploy DSpace 5.4's OAI servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- inside file ${DSPACE_CATALINA_BASE}/conf/Catalina/localhost/OAIHandler.xml
<Context docBase="c:/dspace/webapps/oai">
</Context>
```

So, as the file is named `OAIHandler.xml`, Tomcat deploys the OAI servlet at 
`http://localhost:8080/OAIHandler`.

Accessing a URL such as `http://localhost:8080/OAIHandler/request?verb=Identify` works - the page looks good. Yet links on this page don't use `http://localhost:8080/OAIHandler/...`, but `http://localhost:8080/oai/...` instead.

I don't have any servlet deployed at `/oai`, therefore these links point to nowhere.

I noticed that the configuration file `config/modules/oai.cfg` can have a property `dspace.oai.url`, so I set it to `http://localhost:8080/OAIHandler` - but my problem persists.

I looked into the XSLT stylesheet used by the OAI servlet (`static/style.xsl`). It uses the XSLT expression `/oai:OAI-PMH/oai:request/text()` to construct the beginning part of links. The relevant XML part indeed says `<request verb="Identify">http://localhost:8080/oai/request</request>` instead of the expected `<request verb="Identify">http://localhost:8080/OAIHandler/request</request>`.

Can someone help me point to the wrong configuration and/or Java classes that are responsible for generating the wrong `<request>` XML element?

Comment: It sounds like you have examined the correct files.  One quick thing to try is clearing your oai cache.  Run .../dspace/bin/dspace oai clean-cache to force the pages in the cache to be rebuilt.

Comment: @terrywb, spot on! Now it works. Thank you very much. Would you like to copy your comment to an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have examined the correct files. One quick thing to try is clearing your oai cache. Run .../dspace/bin/dspace oai clean-cache to force the pages in the cache to be rebuilt.